# Is it possible to describe a Singleton Property with SHACL?

Tags: rdf, shacl

Is it possible to describe [Singleton Properties](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4350149/) in SHACL? That is, instead of requiring a single `foaf:name` on a `foaf:Person` there’s a requirement of a unique predicate that that has a `rdf:singletonPropertyOf` of `foaf:name`.

So in

```
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> . 
@prefix rdf:    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

_:person1 a foaf:Person .
_:person1 <name> "Person 1" .
<name> a rdf:Property.
<name> rdf:singletonPropertyOf foaf:name.
_:person2 a foaf:Person.
_:person2 <knows> _:person1.
<knows> a rdf:Property.
<knows> rdf:singletonPropertyOf foaf:knows.
```

`_:person1` is valid but `_:person2` isn’t.

Comment: given that SHACL supports SPARQL for constraints, yes it is possible.

Comment: clearly, nowadays, RDF Star is is dedicated next way for representing statements about statements and might also find it's way into the standard (RDf 1.2/ SPARQL 1.2), so I'd rethink your approach